# Is friendship inherited in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance, friend, access-control

Suppose I have a `Base` class:

```
class Base {
    friend SomeOtherClass;
};
```

And there is another (different) class that inherits from `Base`:

```
class AnotherClass : public Base {}
```

Is friendship inherited as well?

Comment: Yet another question that should have been answered easily using a COMPILER.

Comment: @shoosh: compilers do not necessarily conform to standards. Such a question should be answered by the standard, not compilers.

Comment: @shoosh Which compiler? VS for windows or g++ for unix? Which version of C++ standard? There's many questions you can ask even if you compiler works or doesn't work.

Comment: Perhaps a good question to ask now is can you make it such that friendship is inherited? It would certainly be useful for what I am doing rather than writing out a list of all the classes I want to have "friendship".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In principle, a derived class inherits every member of a base class except:

```
* its constructor and its destructor
* its operator=() members
* its friends
```

So, no. Friends are not inherited.

Comment: It's interesting that you chose the exact wording to say that as this website: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/inheritance/

Comment: Perhaps a good question to ask now is can you make it such that friendship is inherited? It would certainly be useful for what I am doing rather than writing out a list of all the classes I want to have "friendship".

Answer (score 9):

No it isn't.

**Edit:** To quote from the C++ Standard, section 11.4/8

> Friendship is neither inherited nor
>   transitive.

Answer (score 7):

No it isn't, as documented here: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/friends.html#faq-14.4

Comment: The example in the link shows the opposite case to the OP's question. I'd like to add that `SomeOtherClass` will have access to the `Base` fields and methods inherited in objects of `AnotherClass`.