# Friends, Abstract classes and Factory pattern

Tags: c++, inheritance, factory-pattern, friend

Good day to you all...

I'm working on a complex project on my company which I use some wringled Factory Design pattern in the project. Omiting the details; I have some classes (I call them "Devices") which can only be created by "Readers":

```
class DeviceBase // this is a virtual base class
{
  public:
   //some stuff
   friend class ReaderBase; // this is OK and necessary I guess?
  private:
   DeviceBase(); // cannot create a device directly
   //some more stuff
}

class Device1: public DeviceBase // some extended device
{
  public:
   //some stuff 
  private:
   //some more stuff
}

class Device2: public DeviceBase  // some other extended device
{
  public:
   //some stuff

  private:
   //some more stuff
}
```

Now the "Reader", which happens to be factory for devices:

```
class ReaderBase
{
  private:
    DeviceBase[] _devices; // to keep track of devices currently "latched"
  public:
    // some other methods, getters-setters etc ...

    // this method will create the "Devices" :
    virtual bool PollforDevice ( DeviceType, timeout) = 0; 

}
```

Now, this is my factory class; but it's (as you can see) pure virtual. I have special Readers inherit from this one:

```
 class InternalReader: public ReaderBase
 {
   public:
     // define other inherited methods by specifics of this reader
     bool PollforDevice( DeviceType dt, timeout ms)
     {
         switch(dt)
         {
           case Device1: { /* create new device1 and attach to this reader */ } break;
           case Device2: { /* create new device2 and attach to this reader */ } break;
         }
         // show goes on and on...
     }
 }

 class ExternalReader: public Reader
 {
   public:
     // define other inherited methods by specifics of this reader
     bool PollforDevice( DeviceType dt, timeout ms)
     {
         switch(dt)
         {
           case Device1: { /* create new device1 and attach to this reader */ } break;
           case Device2: { /* create new device2 and attach to this reader */ } break;
         }
         // show goes on and on...
     }
 }
```

The reason I use this pattern is: I'm writing for a system that can have multiple of these "readers" attached at the same time and I must use them all at the same time.

And these "Devices": I can make theirs constructor public too, and everyone would be happy; but I want to make sure that they are not created by the code writers themselves (to make sure other coders of it)

Now the questions:

1. Should I explicitly declare in every "Device" that ReaderBase is a friend? Or just declaring at the base "DeviceBase" should be enough?
2. Should I explicitly put in every "Device" that the "Readers" inherited from the "ReaderBase" are also friends of these devices, or just putting ReaderBase is enough?
3. Instead of making whole "ReaderBase" class a friend, can I (and should I) just make the member method "PollforDevice" a friend? Knowing that it's a pure virtual method, would that make inherited copies friends as well?

I'm sorry that the question is a very long one, but I just want to make it clear.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Dont think you can make methods as friend. And [friendship isnt inherited](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597857/is-friendship-inherited-in-c).

Comment: Yes, I know, but in these pattern all I need is to "create instance" - not to reach their "private members" and I think when I made the base class constructor private, I disallow everyone but friends to create an instance; and since it's the base class's constructor private, derived ones cannot be instantiated as well... Or am I incorrect about this assumption?

Comment: You can try, I am actually not too sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why bother about constructability of pure abstract base classes like `DeviceBase`? It can't be constructed anyway if it is a properly designed contract or abstract base class. Unless you have to fit into some kind of framework which you didn't mention, just do the opposite of hiding, e.g.:

```
struct DeviceBase {
    virtual void Foo() = 0;
    virtual void Bar() = 0;
    virtual ~DeviceBase() = default;
};
```

By the way, declaring the constructors or destructors `private` will very effectively make your class "sealed". If for some reason `DeviceBase` is not abstract (which were a serious design flaw in my eyes) make constructors `protected` not `private`. Where you need to bother, is the constructor accessibility of the concrete `Device` classes. Assuming that you are going to "publish" these implementation classes (i.e. their definitions are accessible to users of your library) and you wish to stress that direct construction is prohibited, use the "access idiom" (my invented name for this):

```
namespace impl_detail {
    class DeviceAccess;
}

class ConcreteDevice1 : public DeviceBase {
    friend class impl_detail::DeviceAccess;
    // implementation of DeviceBase and all other stuff go 
    // into the "private" section
};

namespace impl_detail {
    class DeviceAccess {
        template< class TDevice >
        static DeviceBase* Create()
        {
            return new TDevice;
        }
    };
};
```

In your `Reader` classes use `impl_detail::DeviceAccess::Create` to construct `Device` instances, e.g.:

```
// Your ExternalReader::PollForDevice...
switch (dt) {
    case Device1:
        return impl_detail::DeviceAccess::Create<ConcreteDevice1>();
    case Device2: 
        // etc...
}
```

Long story short, best solution is to not publish concrete implementation classes at all, second best some kind of "psychological barrier" which restricts construction, e.g. of the above kind...

Comment: DeviceBase is abstract of course but DeviceX s are not! That "creator-in-the-middle" approach seems nice though: that is a key to solution! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Should I explicitly declare in every "Device" that ReaderBase is a friend? Or just declaring at the base "DeviceBase" should be enough?
> 2. Should I explicitly put in every "Device" that the "Readers" inherited from the "ReaderBase" are also friends of these devices, or just putting ReaderBase is enough?

As friendship is not inherited (at either side of the friendship relation), the only way your scheme will work is when you declare friendship of every derived Reader in every derived Device. This creates a tight coupling between the Reader classes and the Device classes that is not a nice design.

> 3) Instead of making whole "ReaderBase" class a friend, can I (and should I) just make the member method "PollforDevice" a friend? Knowing that it's a pure virtual method, would that make inherited copies friends as well?

You could make `ReaderX::PollforDevice` a friend instead of the entire `ReaderX` class, but it won't help you much and only opens the door for hard to resolve circular dependencies.

---

Actually, it is quite hard to create a design where classes of hierarchy X can only be created by classes of hierarchy Y and no one else, without creating a tight coupling between the classes in both hierarchies.
My approach would be

1. First and foremost, educate your coworkers that if they want a `DeviceX`, then they can obtain it from a `ReaderY` and in no other way. Make sure this is enforced in code reviews.
   All the other steps are just damage control.
2. Make sure only the `BaseDevice` class gets exposed to code outside the Reader's implementation.
3. Make the *destructor* of all Device classes protected. This ensures that Device classes can only be cleaned up by derived classes or friends (and automatically rules out stack allocation by non-friends). Should get someone to think twice if they accidentally try to use a Device class directly.
4. Make the `ReaderBase` a friend of `DeviceBase` and give `ReaderBase` a function to do the actual cleanup of a Device. This is needed to ensure Devices *can* be cleaned up.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I'll stray from formal representations this time to make something works :)

Comment: Now thinking, you actually imply that if I make ReaderBase friend and destructors protected (and why not constructors too), I can achieve what I want! So as long as PollforDevice is a virtual declared function in ReaderBase, that does cleaning and instancing, I'm good to go, right?

Comment: @AhmetIpkin: Making the constructors protected does not add anything, because then you would again need to declare the factory classes a friend of everything they could create. For destructors, you don't have that problem, because you can use the polymorphic behaviour of the destructor and only invoke it through a pointer to the base class (ideally from a single point in the base class of the factory hierarchy).